# The system is running in low-graphics mode error in “Virtualbox”

Tags: virtualbox

Hi guys this error just popped up in my VirtualBox. After the error screen shows up, I press command+F1(I use a Macbook) and a command line comes to the screen that wants me to login. After logging in, i tried

```
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclear
```

then press command+F8 but same error still remains.

Comment: When you enter your password with `sudo` nothing is displayed this is by design.  Just type your password and press ENTER. If you do not get an error message it worked.  If you do then what's the error.  You can reset the password if you have forgotten it by following [these insructions](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/107450)

Comment: I solved that problem but now i could not solve my main problem. Ubuntu still shows the same error. I tried 

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

but still got the same problem.

I also tried to remove virtual box and reinstalled both vb and ubuntu.

Comment: Edit the question with the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't mentioned the version of VirtualBox nor the version of the system you were installing, I'll describe the solution I've found for VB v4.1.12 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS guest machine.

This OS version was installed with X Server from quantal (12.10) and displayed error message about low-graphics mode. When you remove this error window using Esc and log in using console, try to uninstall current X Server from quantal from the guest machine:

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-core-lts-quantal
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

As soon as this will be done, default core X Server will be installed automatically. If this will not happen, try to install it manually (including all its dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

After reboot guest OS should work properly.